# Background image in stylesheet won't appear

Tags: css

Hi I'm a new developer and I'm trying to build a portfolio site for myself. Anyway, I can't seem to get the background image I put together to show. The image is located in the images folder of my CSS folder. I notice if I try to put a background color in it works just fine. However, I don't want a background color just an image.
[image]
The file pathway in my project is as follows:

ProjectName > SiteRoot > CSS > images > hmebckgnd.jpg

**This is my code for styles.css**

```
body{
                background-image: url('/images/hmebckgnd.jpg');                  
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin: 0;




            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `/` in the path attempts to find the images folder from the root directory, removing it will load it relative to the directory the stylesheet is in (which should be the CSS folder):

```
body{
    background-image: url('images/hmebckgnd.jpg');                  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3473475 is this all of the relevant CSS? Are you sure the filenames are correct?

Comment: I'll check again but I'm pretty sure

Comment: I use the exact same pathway as I used for my logo and buttons and they work just fine.

Comment: @user3473475 There seems to be something else at play here. Could you post a screenshot of your directory tree with all the relevant folders expanded? Also if you have any other CSS that would be valuable as well.

Comment: I changed the name of the image to something simpler. It's now 'hb,jpg'

Comment: @user3473475 in your screenshot you have the url as `css/images/`, it should just be `images/`.

Comment: I tried it that way and that didn't work either. So I copy and pasted the pathway for my logo image which works and swapped out the logo image for my background image. That's why that's why I put it in like that like that.

Comment: @user3473475 I'm at a loss. The path is relative to the stylesheet directory, so `images/` is the correct way to target it. Your browser log shows that `css/images/` attempts to navigate to `css/css/images/` because of this. Are you sure it's a `jpg` and not a `png` or something?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've been using Netbeans IDE but I think I'll start the project in Dreamweaver. Maybe I'll have better luck. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I found out what my issue was sort of. I think my image was too big. When  I used a standard image it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your image has path like this: 
ProjectName > SiteRoot > CSS > images > hmebckgnd.jpg

why don't you include css directory in css file?

```
body{
                background-image: url('../images/hmebckgnd.jpg');                  
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin: 0;

            }
```

It is good practice to use relative path in css file and load whole css file with forward slash in your HTML file.

Comment: Sorry your css file is porbably in css directory, but images are in images directory. So you have to move back to /siteRoot and then go to images its done by ../images